# Is a compact kahler manifold with non-zero Neron-Severi groups projective?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

In Huybrechts' book 《complex geometry》 p251, there is a statement: A compact Kahler manifold $X$ is projective if and only if $K_X\cap H^2(X,\Bbb Z)\neq 0$, where $K_X$ means the Kahler cone of $X$. And we know Kahler cone is contained in $H^{1,1}(X)$, so we get $K_X\cap H^2(X,\Bbb Z)=K_X\cap H^{1,1}(X)\cap H^2(X,\Bbb Z)=K_X\cap H^{1,1}(X,\Bbb Z)$, we know that $H^{1,1}(X,\Bbb Z)$ is the Neron-Severi group of $X$, so if the Neron-Severi group of $X$ is $0$, we say $X$ can never be projective by the theorem stated above, but on the other hand, if the Neron-Severi group of $X$ is not $0$, can we get the concusion that $X$ must be projective? Or any counter examples?

Comment: What if $Y$ is a non-projective compact Kahler manifold, and you consider $X := Y\times \mathbb{P}^1$? That's not projective. What is its Neron-Severi group?

Comment: @Ariyan Javanpeykar, sorry, I can't see why $Y\times \mathbb{P}^1$ is not projective, by Kodaira's embedding theorem prove there is not a Hodge metric of it? and I don't know how to compute the Neron-Severi group of $Y\times \mathbb{P}^1$, I guess you mean it will be non-zero, thus we get a counter example?

Comment: Suppose it is projective. Then isn't $Y\cong Y\times \{pt\}\subset Y\times \mathbb{P}^1$ a closed subset, hence also projective (contradiction)? To see that the Neron-Severi group is non-trivial you just have to write down one non-trivial divisor. We just did, no?

Comment: @Ariyan Javanpeykar, thanks for your helpful comments, so you mean treat $Y$ as the hypersuface of $Y\times \mathbb{P}^1$ and the corresponding divisor is the non-trivial divisor, but how to compute its Chern class to see it's non-zero? or any reference book?

Comment: I didn't check whether the class of $Y\times \{\infty\}$ is non-zero in $NS(Y\times \mathbb{P}^1)$. Here's what you can try: first show it is non-zero in $Pic(Y\times \mathbb{P}^1)$. I mean, assume there is a meromorphic function $f$ whose divisor equals $Y\times \{0\}$. You can restrict this meromorphism function maybe to $\{pt\}\times \mathbb{P}^1$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: Maybe my computing method is diffrent from yours, I learned from Kodaira's book《complex manifolds》, to compute the Chern class of a holomorphic line bundle, first we choose a Hermitian meric of this line bundle, use the Chern connection we compute the curvature form which represent the Chern class, but I don't see how to use this method to prove the Chern class of holomorphic line bundle of $Y\times \mathbb{P}^1$ is non-zero.