# $H^{1,1}(X) \cap H^2(X,\mathbb Z)\neq 0$ implies $\mathcal K_X \cap H^2(X,\mathbb Z) \neq \emptyset$?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifold, $\mathcal K_X$ be the Kähler cone of $X$, if we have $H^{1,1}(X) \cap H^2(X,\mathbb Z)\neq 0$, then can we get $\mathcal K_X \cap H^2(X,\mathbb Z) \neq \emptyset$?

At first, I think it is true because I have a "proof": since the Kähler cone $\mathcal K_X$ forms an open set in $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb R)$ (see p130 of Huybrechts'《complex geometry》), and $H^{1,1}(X) \cap H^2(X,\mathbb Z)\neq 0$ implies $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb R) \cap H^2(X,\mathbb Q)\neq 0$, we know rational points $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, so an open set $\mathcal K_X$ in $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb R)$ also contains rational points in $H^2(X,\mathbb Q)$, thus $\mathcal K_X \cap H^2(X,\mathbb Q) \neq \emptyset$.

But as I have asked a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3701218/is-a-compact-kahler-manifold-with-non-zero-neron-severi-groups-projective), I think I have gotten a counter-example provided by @Ariyan Javanpeykar: let $Y$ be a non-projective compact Kähler manifold, take $X=Y\times \mathbb CP^1$, then $X$ is not projective. And we know that $X$ is projective if and only if $\mathcal K_X \cap H^2(X,\mathbb Z) \neq \emptyset$ (cited from p251 of Huybrechts' 《complex geometry》), since $X$ is not projective, we get $\mathcal K_X \cap H^2(X,\mathbb Z) = \emptyset$. But compute the Neron-Severi group of $X$, we have $H^{1,1}(X) \cap H^2(X,\mathbb Z)\neq 0$, so it answers negatively my question.

Can anyone figure out what mistakes I have made in my "proof"? Thanks!

Comment: $\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb Q} H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb R) \cap H^2(X, \mathbb Q)$ could be $< \operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb R} H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb R)$ so $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb R) \cap H^2(X, \mathbb Q)$ is not necessary dense inside $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @kp9r4d, can you give a concrete example? For example let $H^2(X,\mathbb R)=\mathbb R^3$, the coordinates are $x,y,z$, let $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb R)$ be a plane in it, then take $H^{1,1}$ to be $y=\sqrt{2}x$ in $\mathbb R^3$, does it satisfy your argument?

Comment: Yes, why not, in your example $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb R) \cap H^2(X,\mathbb Q) = \{(0,0,t) \in H^2(X,\mathbb Q) = \mathbb Q^3 | t \in \mathbb Q\}$ hence, $\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb Q} H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb R) \cap H^2(X,\mathbb Q) = 1$ and $\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb R} H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb R) = 2$

Comment: @kp9r4d, thanks, it make sense!